# Github develop branch merge to master showing more history than expected

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

Been using `production/integration` branches to manage code promo to production. Our `integration` branch is a stable integration environment that all feature branches are made from, and merges are reviewed by PR, and deployed via CI when approved and squashed+merged. Once `integration` is stable and we've tested it, we do another PR from `integration` to `production`. When this is approved and squashed+merged, CI takes over and deploys to the production env.

```
git checkout integration
git checkout -b feature
# do work
git add/commit etc
# create PR, squash+merge on github UI when reviewed
# CI sees new commit to integration, deploys to int env
```

My issue is with what these `integration -> production` PRs looks like when they are reviewed - even though (at times) I've done the following to get any commits already in `production` into `integration`:

```
git checkout integration
git pull
git pull origin production
git push
# create PR for integration merge into production
```

When I go look at the PR page on Github, the list of commits shows history going back to commits that are already represented in `production`. The "Files changed" list is very small, while the commit history goes back many PRs ago. I thought `git pull origin production` would remove this history and then only show the new commits coming from `integration` to `production`?

Am I missing some obvious way to maintain merge commits but also clean up the history when `integration` is merged into `production`? Could inconsistent merging/rebasing strategies cause this?

Some screenshots to show what is confusing - a PR that has a *single* file changed from a single commit, but the commit history goes back much further:

[image]

The single file change was the last commit in the list—why does the PR show commits that have already been merged previously? I thought Squashing and Merging (both into `integration` from feature branches and into master from `integration` would remove this commit history and make merges into master clean?

[image]

The green arrow represents the 1 file changed in this PR, and I thought the commit history (after a merge of `production` back into `integration` to clean the history, if any) would only have that one commit.

Is this a github display bug or am I missing some principle of how git maintains commit history across a long-running branch that gets merged into another long running branch? It's always a one-way merge, from `integration` into `production` branch, for CI to deploy the update.